# In ggplot how do I eliminate wasted space below 0 on the axis?

Tags: r

I would like to eliminate the the dead space in the chart below the two 0's. How would I do this?

I'm not sure how to have the wording more clear. An image would have worked best to explain what I'm looking for but Stackoverflow didn't let me post one.

My code is:

```
ggplot(data=temp,
  aes(x=s, y=SumOfAverage,))  + 
    geom_line() +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1),labels = percent_format())+
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 35000, by = 1000),labels = comma_format())+
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
labs(y = "kWh")+
opts(
        panel.grid.major.x = theme_line(size = 0.1, colour = '#1391FF'),
    panel.grid.major.y = theme_line(size = 0.1, colour = '#1391FF'),
        panel.grid.minor = theme_line(colour = "lightblue"),
        panel.background = theme_rect(colour = "grey"),
        axis.ticks = theme_blank()
    )+
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))
```

Comment: Who knows, we do not have your data and cannot see the chart! Make a reproducible example using one of the built in datasets or your own toy example.  Likely you are looking for `expand = c(0,0)` which you need to add to your `scale_x/y_continuous` elements.

Comment: I did this `temp <- data.frame(s = runif(1000), SumOfAverage = runif(1000, 0, 35000))` and do not see any wasted space. Also, you are using a bunch of deprecated options.